# can not be updated resolv.conf file in slackware

Tags: linux, unix, slackware

Recently, I set up a slackware box, but some questions trouble me.

1. I fire up the netconfig route using the dhcp configuration, after that I can't access the network. I issue the ping command for google.com, but I got the ping unknown server google message.                                                2. Secondly, I change  the dhcp config to static IP by editing the /etc/rc.d/rc.inet1.conf, filling the static ip, then updating the /etc/resolv.conf file for dns config. Here, I got the mess, when I saving the file, it pops up the message "writing the file when it reading", I opened it again when I saved. I lossed all my edit.

I think this problem is because the dhcp service update this file. But I really don't know how to resolve it.

Anyone deal with this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The file /etc/resolv.conf is owned by root, so you need to either be logged in as root, su to root or use sudo when editing it. Also, it would help if you could cut and paste the error message instead of writing what you remember.